# Data synchronization between tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization

I have two tables (let's call them A and B) with same structure and i need to synchronize data in them...

There's one primary key field, with same value in both tables, and several fields with value in table A and null (or obsolete value that need to be replaced with current value from table A) in table B... I need to copy value from table A to table B.

Is there any easy way (other than replication) to do this in mySQL 4.1?

thanks in advance

Comment: `JOIN` 2 tables on the primary key and issue an `UPDATE` query?

Comment: use LEFT JOIN to identify your NULL records in the second table then use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/insert-select.html as answered below

Comment: @SergeyBenner actually, i made an error in question... some fields have null value, some has obsolete value that need to be replaced so your answer won't work, but thanks anyway....

Comment: Check INSERT IGNORE or INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statements for your merging needs. Check also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/replace.html REPLACE INTO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
UPDATE table_b b, table_a a 
SET b.field1 = a.field1, b.field2 = a.field2  
WHERE b.primary_key = a.primary_key
```

add the fields as required.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do:

INSERT INTO table1 (field1,field2,field3)
SELECT field1,field2,field3
FROM table2;

Or do you actually already have data in table2 and you need to update it rather than insert new columns?